# MySQL or Derby ? for online java chat server?

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, chat, derby

i am builds online chat application , using Applets and java chat server , the application will hold many connections and a lot of rooms ,

i used Derby , but i am worry about it's power of many connections and many queries , and solid of queries which it support ?

so i am thinking also in **MySQL** , but i don't know if it's ideal also for this type of application ? or **Derby** is the best ?

Thank you ,

Comment: The question is highly opinion based.  It also depends on your practical scaling needs.  If you're not going to need to scale heavily, then it doesn't really matter what DB you choose.  If this does need to be highly scalable, then ANY relational database is going to choke.  In my personal opinion, given that most of the data in a chat service is immutable, a write optimized NoSQL solution like Cassandra seems like a good fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well try the comparison first [MySql vs Derby](http://database-management-systems.findthebest.com/saved_compare/MySQL-vs-Derby)

Developing any application with embedded system we should think about Direct database connection, easy to update and alter the schema,  easy to remove/handle data inconsistency, easy to backup and restore data easily. After finding these out, which RDBMS would be beneficial, is mostly up to you, as *opinion will always vary*.

MySql's innoDB can be configured to hyperthread read threads, hyperthread write threads with accessing multiple CPUs/Cores and efficient Buffer Pool; It's performance is quite good.

As the linked page is showing the differences: For for Derby's *Full text, Hash, R-/R+ Tree for indexing capability* and *Range, Hash, Composite(Range + hash) for partitioning capability*; My opinion is, if my JAVA application in server side, has also a client side  which will need a database embedded, i would consider to go for Derby.

[This is the article](http://home.online.no/~olmsan/publications/pres/apachecon05us/apachecon05.pdf), i read prior to start Derby, it has a nice description and performance comparison with MySql using graph and charts.

Comment: Thank you , the database will not be embedded in the client side , but will be in tge server side , and the client side will connect to it remotely or using API

Comment: go through the article i have linked. I just didn't want to write same thing when it is already written somewhere else. I think this article will give you a positive guideline for Derby.